# Get the generic type of another type

Tags: angular, typescript

Suppose I have this :

```js
const sub = new Subject<{  id: string; value: string; }>();
```

How can I get the generic type given to the Subject ?

```js
const item: ??? = { id: '1', value: 'value' };
```

I am aware that I can declare an interface, or simply give the exact same type to my item. What I would like to know is if there is a way to get the generic type of another type in a more global way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can infer the generic type:

```
const sub = new Subject<{  id: string; value: string; }>();
type Unwrap<T extends Subject<unknown>> = T extends Subject<infer K> ?  K : never;
type Item = Unwrap<typeof sub>;
var item: Item = {
  id: '1',
  value: '2'
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCuAjAVgU2AFwDwBUB80A3gL4BQpwA9gHYQbQRLQC801qA7nEmplodGgBLACYAuBhgBOQ6gHMA3NABuYEPFQS6M+UuJ4AFAEoFpDAE8ADqmgBVahylhLuaKgAeGVNREwEKdGx4agBrakoOajwCVhw3T29fbgC+WQAzVCloAGkCAH5BbOgJdmVM0wtraABJLwBbFjsHJxdK1Eo0hiQ8U1UsoXqJWtQG1kJSQVEJAHIARmmAGgmVNQ0ZgCZp0jIgA)