# Get Angular Type<> from component instance in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, factory

First of all, I wanted to make clear that what I want is the Angular [Type](https://angular.io/api/core/Type) instance of a component, not the TypeScript definition of that component.

The context is the following:
I'm inside a service and I receive in input the instance of a component (`HomeComponent` with all the component properties specified). I can also access the *ViewContainerRef* and the *TemplateRef*. However, I didn't find anything that I can pass to [resolveComponentFactory](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactoryResolver#methods) to obtain a new instance of the object.

I tried:

```
component = *component instance*
componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component)
```

But it throws the following error:

> No component factory found for [object Object]. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Obviously the component is correctly imported (I've an instance of it!).

I tried different combinations with the same result, but I still can't get the `Type` instance that Angular wants.

I don't know a priori the list of possible components, so I can't use a map or import them in the service. How can I obtained the wanted instance?

I'm currently using Angular5, so I still need the ComponentFactoryResolver.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the generic type of another type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74760332/get-the-generic-type-of-another-type)

Comment: Other than that, which version of Angular are you using ? The component factory resolver does not need to be used anymore

Comment: @MGX that's unrelated, I'm not talking about the TypeScript type but the Angular `Type` class. You're right about the version, I'm going to edit the question

Comment: I was afraid so, the answer is no, you can't. You can't use a type as a value.

Comment: The `Type` is a concrete JavaScript object :) please, refer the blue link in the first line of the question

Comment: Oh I totally missed the point of your question. But in that case, why are you sending the component instance ? Why aren't you sending the class of that instance instead ?

Comment: I'm not actually sending it, I'm reading it from the `TemplateRef` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through experimentation, I found out that the `Angular` [Type](https://angular.io/api/core/Type) instance is actually a string representing the constructor of the component.

For this reason, it was as easy as:

```
componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component.constructor)
```